# retrieving image from data return to include it in a dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good Day developers  im just playing around with dropdowns and wonder how could i retrieve image already store in data return as a string path to its in my assets , in order to display it in my dropdown.
Here my case:

first the data return array of objects where in i store the images and other item

```
Data Return

rateScale:[
          {Points:5 ,src: require("../assets/5stars.png")},
          {Points:4 ,src: require("../assets/4stars.png")},
          {Points:3 ,src: require("../assets/3stars.png")},
          {Points:2 ,src: require("../assets/2stars.png")},
          {Points:1 ,src: require("../assets/1stars.png")},
      ],
```

then on my computed properties i get a function which iterating over this object my get the dropdown build .

```
COMPUTED PROPERTIES

    computedRates(){
      let setRate=new Set();
       this.rateScale.forEach(element => {
        setRate.add( element.Points)
      });
      return Array.from(setRate)

    },
```

if i try to access only the item Points in the object like this former function sets, works perfect:[image]

But if i try to instead of item Points adress it to the src in order to charge the Images, lets say:

```
computedRates(){
      let setRate=new Set();
       this.rateScale.forEach(element => {
        setRate.add( element.src)
      });
      return Array.from(setRate)

    },
```

this is the result:
[image]

My idea is to to make the images to show up, and concatenate them with th Points item, like sort kind of

DropDown:

5 Image
4 Image
3 Image
2 Image
1 image

So could you give me any advice about how to make the images to show up in my drop down.Must to say each image path i correct.Thanks in advance!!!!And have a good day!!!

Comment: You've gotten the bundled paths for the images correctly, but dropdown options have no `src` attribute to set, so it doesn't help.  You would need a custom dropdown widget to use image files like that.

Comment: Thanks Dan ...i will adress my search about this widgets ...thanks!!!